# Big O time complexity when running time is affected by data values

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

Given a non-empty array which stores unbounded positive numbers (eg. BigInteger), what is the Big O runtime complexity of this pseudo-code algorithm:

```
function snoozy(inputArray) {
   var arraySize = inputArray.size
   var firstValue = inputArray[0]   // firstValue is always >= 1

   loop (i from 1 to arraySize) {
      loop (j from 1 to firstValue) {
         <perform a constant time operation with i & j mutating state>
      }
   }
}
```

Suppose the runtime complexity is O(g(n)) where n is the length of the array and g(n) is some function.  Then there must exist fixed constants C > 0 and n0 > 0 such that f(n) <= C * g(n) for all n >= n0.  However, I could supply an array with the first element value = (C + 1) * g(n) therefore the number of iterations is greater than C * g(n) so f(n) cannot be O(g(n)).

From what I can tell, specifying the runtime complexity only in terms of the size of the array will not guarantee an upper bound because I could always provide an input where the first array element value is even larger.

What is the runtime complexity of this algorithm using Big O notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. We cannot just use the size here. If `n` is the size of the array, and `m` is the first element, the complexity is given by:

`O(n*m)`

Answer (score 0):

The complexity will be - `O(arraySize*digits(firstValue))`

Now let us take a look at `BigIntegers` itself:

In this case, `inputArray` is storing `BigIntegers`. Regarding `BigIntegers`, there is no theoretical limit. The `BigInteger` class allocates as much memory as it needs for all the bits of data it is asked to hold. It is totally implementation dependent, how much data you are storing in it. It will depend on how much your RAM will be able to hold.

Here is the minimum supported range in case of Java8:

```
-2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE) (exclusive) to +2^(Integer.MAX_VALUE) (exclusive)
```

Comment: Doesn't Big O just look at the growth rate setting aside hardware limitations?

Operating systems can use paging to work around RAM limitations.  Although the access time would be affected, the Big O complexity in terms of the number of operations performed ignores access times.  

Alternatively, you could always buy more RAM.